# A Program that Checks Consecutive Letters - Java

Tags: java, string, alphabetical

I'm looking for help with a question I have. We just started learning simple java in our course after learning a tonne of C++.

One of our bonus missions for people who know code more than what was taught in class.

The mission is as follows: **Write a function by the name lettersSeries which gets letters (one letter at a time, assume all letters are lower case) inputted from the user. The function stops accepting letters from the user once the user has inputted 3 consecutive letters. *(Only for loops can be used without while loops)***

Example: a -> b -> a -> **c -> d -> e (Here is stops)**

As far I don't know much and I would be happy if someone would help me with this... I tried some options but I have no idea how to trace the alphabet, and especially how to check if letters are consecutive...

Thanks!

```
public static void letterSeries() {
    //We create a scanner for the input
    Scanner letters = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(Here I need the for loop to continue the letters input) {
      //Here I need to know if to use a String or a Char...
      String/Char letter = next.<//Char or String>();
      if(Here should be the if statement to check if letters are consecutive) {
          /*
              Here should be
              the rest of the code
              I need help with
          */
```

Obviously, you could change the code, and not make my pattern, I would just be happier with an easier way!

Comment: try writing some code. do a google search . when you get stuck . tell us the specific issue and we will be happyly aid you with .

Comment: Hint: to trace for consecutive letters, save the letter before and check with current if distance is 1. While distance is 1, increment a var, if not, reset var to 0. When var is 3, stop. Put some more effort (code), and come back if you have a problem.

Comment: If you know how to solve it with a `while` loop, it's easy enough to turn that into a `for` loop. The loop `while (<cond>) { ... }` can just as easily be written as a `for` loop with empty initialize and increment parts: `for (; <cond>;) { ... }`. Perhaps not in the spirit of the assignment, but it obeys the letter of the law. :)

Comment: I'm stuck with how to check if letters are consecutive...

Comment: Letters are consecutive if `newLetter - currentLetter == 1`. You may need to deal with case changes first before applying this test.

Comment: But what type of var should I input my letters in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle the problem, I'm going to let you fill in the blanks with this though so I don't do all of your homework for you.

```
private void letterSeries() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char prevChar;
    char currChar;
    int amountOfConsecutives = 0;
    final int AMOUNT_OF_CONSECUTIVES = 2;

    for(;;) {
        // Take in the users input and store it in currChar
        // Check if (prev + 1) == currChar
            // If true, amountOfConsecutives++
            // If false, amountOfConsecutives = 0;
        // If amountOfConsecutives == AMOUNT_OF_CONSECUTIVES
            // Break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, just what I needed. Although can we just simply use the method of subtracting and instead check if currChar - prevChar = 1?

Comment: That would work for every case except for when a user inputs `z` followed by an `a`. Hint: Look at an ASCII Table to see why that would fail.

Comment: I think you probably want `prevChar + 1 == curChar` rather than the other way around. And you certainly don't need the `% 26` part.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the ASCII chart method.

Comment: Oops, @TedHopp is right. You do not need to look at the ASCII values of the characters. Updated the answer to fix this.

Comment: @user123 Why should "a" be treated as consecutive to "z"?

Comment: @user123 I've tried to write the whole code then by myself, with your pattern. Only I'm thinking where should I get the prevChar from? We should provide **only** the first inputted letter to the prevChar var?

Comment: Initially prevChar will be `NULL`, at the end of the for loop you want to set `prevChar = currChar`.

Comment: @user123 Where should I set the value of AMOUNT_OF_CONSECUTIVES at?

Comment: Inside of the method, I just updated the answer to show that. You won't need it outside of the scope of the method.

Comment: @user123 Also, my program says that prevChar is still not defined. Can I define it as null in the start? Could you edit to show me how to do that?

Comment: @NickS. right that's because `NULL` won't be able to be converted into a `char` type. The most simple way to work around this would be to do `char prevChar = '|';` or something like that, instantiate the `prevChar` to some non-alphabetic character at the beginning. The alternative would be to set it to `NULL`, then doing an `if(prevChar != null) { // Then the check to see if prev+1 == currChar }`

Comment: @user123 BTW I found an error in your code... You should set AMOUNT_OF_CONSECUTIVES = 2 instead of 3... Don't forget that this loop doesn't stop unless we have the condition met, so if you set it to 3 it will run 4 times until stopping, thus needing 4 consecutive letters and not 3. But other then that the code ran smoothly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use chars' Unicode number to check if letters are consecutive: if a and b are your letters, try to check if b - a == 1. If consequentiality is intended in a case-insensitive way ('B' consecutive to 'a') then check: (b - a == 1 || b - a == 33).

Comment: In Java, it would be their Unicode value, not their ASCII code, but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: So I can still use this method in java? If I write an if statement with this type of check, will it work?

Comment: Try it and let us know. Use chars as primitive type for your vars.

Comment: Instead of using 33, just use `Character.toLowerCase` on all letters. (Or `String.toLowerCase`, if reading the characters as strings.)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, now updated... We assume all letter inputted are lower case, so cases are not a matter...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void letterSeries() {        
    Scanner letters = new Scanner(System.in);
    String last = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for (;counter < 2;){
        if ( last.equals (last=letters.next())) counter ++;
        else counter = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reset the counter when letters aren't consecutive. Also, the termination test should be `counter < 3`. This also requires that letters be separated by delimiters, which may or may not be what OP needs.

Comment: Well can't I just break the loop then?

Comment: @TedHopp Ups, I forgot to reset the counter. The termination condition is correct, try if you don't believe it

Comment: You're right about the termination condition; it was a fencepost error on my part. However, you still need to use `for` instead of `while`. It doesn't even compile as is and OP can't use `while`.

Comment: Ups, i messed up while fixing it... I'd better go home now

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner letters = new Scanner(System.in);
char previousChar = '\0';
int consecutive = 1;
for(; consecutive != 3 ;){
    char userInput= letters.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    if (userInput - previousChar == 1){
        consecutive++;
    } else {
        consecutive = 1;
    }
    previousChar = userInput;
}
```

I cheated a little bit with this solution. I used a for loop with only the middle part so it acts like a while loop.

Anyway, here's how it works.

The first three lines create a scanner for user input, a `consecutive` variable that counts how many consecutive letters the user enters, and a `previousChar` to store the previous character.

"Why does `consecutive` start at 1?" you might ask. Well if the user enters one letter, it is going to be consecutive with itself.

In the for loop, as long as `consecutive != 3`, the code is going to run. The first line in the loop we read a character using `findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0)`. And then the if statement checks whether it is a consecutive letter with the previous character. If it is, add one to `consecutive` and if not, reset `consecutive` to one. Lastly, we set `previousChar` to `userInput` to prepare for the next iteration.